# Defect on profile page: vertical line consisting of zeros

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page

I have no idea what this is nor how to describe it but it looks like a bug to me.

Funny thing is, I tried visiting other users' profile pages but this "error" only appears on iBug's profile page. No idea why.

> [image]

Comment: I've seen that user use that kind of stuff before in e.g. the Sandbox (deleted post link: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/315869/369802, look at the revision history). I wouldn't be surprised if they did this themselves ;)

Comment: @Tinkeringbell wouldn't that be considered a defacement?

Comment: Hmm. I'll ask around, I'm not sure myself. It looks quite harmless, though it's confusing.

Comment: Looks like a bunch of combining characters placed in the Location field.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, I've checked, and this isn't a bug.

This user set a bunch of [combining characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character) in their location field (where users are supposed to enter their 'location') themselves. Like I said in the comments, they're known to be fond of these characters (See the revision history of this [deleted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/315869/369802) in the formatting sandbox).

For now, this is just confusing, and it doesn't seem to be breaking anything.  <s>I've asked around, and this is one of those things moderators generally don't intervene with, so I'm not going to reset the location field/profile.</s>  After a few more people chimed in, it was determined this was enough of a disturbance to reset. So it was.

Comment: They also once changed their *username* to a sequence of these combining characters, and it had to be reset by a moderator. (Interestingly, it was preventing their chat profile from syncing, so a mod had to do that manually as well.)

Comment: Oooooooh, it l000ked like it was generated from the top bar, not rising upwards from the geography/location icon below. I see!

Comment: But why is the line "verticle" and not horizontal??

Comment: @Mari-LouA See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579844/how-does-zalgo-text-work

Comment: No more Zalgo text --- IBug -> https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/379000/965146

Comment: While not being a bug, it is still very annoying. It even shows up in the user's expanded usercard.

Comment: Anything that breaks out of the boundaries of a field is something a mod can and should remove. This can break other parts of the UI, and it's generally confusing and disruptive