# Issue found in the formatting sandbox

Tags: bug

Just on the first page of [Formatting Sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox), I saw a strange right-tilted "line":

[image]

Is it a kind of bug?

Comment: Related (possibly duplicate of): [Defect on profile page: vertical line consisting of zeros](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/323037/289905).

Comment: I've removed the comment that had the Zalgo. If you ever see anything like it in the Sandbox again, feel free to flag such comments as 'no longer needed'.

Comment: @SebastianSimon it could be considered as a duplicate, but in fact there are some differences , you link is abou profile, mine about post/answer/comment. But at all this is the same internal engine, but as to my question Rob answer is most accurate.

Comment: @MichałLipok But it’s Unicode characters. It doesn’t matter if it’s on someone’s profile, on someone’s post, or on a Wikipedia article. It’s all the same cause.

Comment: Related: [Strange comment text covers up top tabs on SE android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/198044/289905).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No it's not a bug, it's Zalgo text.

It's formed using [combining characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combining_character).

N̴̡̘͌͛o̸͍͕͖̓̚ i̵͙͉͌͘͠t̸͉̺͔̽͋͋'̵͙͔͓̒̈́͊s̵̫̠̦͊̕͝ n̸͎͇̝̓̕͝o̸͚͎̐́̿͜t̵̡̝̽̓ ä̵̢̼̼́͐͠ b̴͚̞͋͆u̴͍̻̦̒͠͝g̸̙̟̽͘͠,̸̞͚͇́͑̚ i̴͓̘͇͛͊͝t̴̞̦͉̀̓̾'̴̺̪͚̈́̈́͝s̵̞̞̠̓͐̾ Z̵̘͓̼̓̿a̵̪͖̺̒͋l̴͕͕͍̓̽̀g̴̠̪͙̓̒͠o̵̞͍̫̽̚ t̸͙̙̼͊͝͠e̸̟̘͎͛̈́́x̴͇̺͉͊͆t̸͍͎̫̀̚̕.̸̪̘͎̓͑̿

Answer (score 11):

Nope!  The Sandbox is where we test stuff, so it's bound to look a bit strange (blockquotes in the scrollbar, etc).  That particular black line is caused by Zalgo text.